# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define. Quickblox

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, quickblox

I'm trying to use [quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android) chat in my android app and get this error:

```
[2014-04-28 11:08:29 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define     Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;
[2014-04-28 11:08:29 - ICY] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;
```

QB contains org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity but I can't find out which of other jars contains it too. Here is a list of all needed jars:

1. google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
2. google-api-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar
3. google-api-services-plus-v1-1.3.0-beta.jar
4. google-http-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
5. google-oauth-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
6. jackson-core-asl-1.9.1.jar
7. google-play-services.jar
8. android-support-v4.jar
9. signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
10. signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
11. quickblox-android-1.1.0.jar

Is there any other way to handle this problem except of writing special ClassLoader?

Comment: are you using library project? check your library project too. is their any common library?

Comment: You're right! I was looking for conflicting jars in my library projects but i missed a package org.apache.http.entity.mime in one of these projects (facepalm). Thanks a lot!

Comment: have u find the solution?